# im have trouble with error checking and looping

Tags: python-2.7, loops, error-handling

This is a multi file code so all parts will be needed to run it, as is the code works as intended which is to select 2 pokemon form a text file and have the user and computer select the attack type.

The problem i'm having is getting the battle function to loop and then preventing cheating by error checking to make sure that a valid attack was used and that only a str was entered.

Im not asking for you to flat out do all the work for me but i'm stuck and don't know what else todo so any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import random
from fileopenpoke import select_random

f = open('pokemon.txt', 'r',)
l = f.read().splitlines()

# important things
# the attacks
Attack = ["Air", "Water", "Grass"]

# Score/attack
def poke_score():
    score = random.choice(Attack)
    return score

# things
user_poke = select_random(l)
enemy_poke = select_random(l)
enemy_score = poke_score()

# staging
print ("5 matches Best 3 out of 5")
print user_poke, "Vs.", enemy_poke
print ("Select Attack")

# user select attack
def make_score():
    score = raw_input("Air Water or Grass")
    return score
user_score = make_score()
# error checking
# output and battle sequence
def battle():
    global user_score, enemy_score
    etal = 0
    utal = 0
    match = 0
# forfeits match if no attack or incorrect attack is given

    if user_score == "Air" and enemy_score == "Grass":
        etal = etal + 1
        match = match + 1
        print enemy_poke, "used", enemy_score, user_poke, "used", user_score, enemy_poke, "Match Won!"
        print "current score", utal, "/", etal
        print "match", match
        return etal, match

    elif user_score == "Grass" and enemy_score == "Water":
        etal = etal + 1
        match = match + 1
        print enemy_poke, "used", enemy_score, user_poke, "used", user_score, enemy_poke, "Match Won!"
        print "current score", utal, "/", etal
        print "match", match
        return etal, match

    elif user_score == "Water" and enemy_score == "Air":
        etal = etal + 1
        match = match + 1
        print enemy_poke, "used", enemy_score, user_poke, "used", user_score, enemy_poke, "Match Won!"
        print "current score", utal, "/", etal
        print "match", match
        return etal, match

    elif user_score == enemy_score:
        match = match + 1
        print enemy_poke, "used", enemy_score, user_poke, "used", user_score, "Match was a Tie!!"
        print "match", match
        return match

    else:
        utal = utal + 1
        match = match + 1
        print enemy_poke, "used", enemy_score, user_poke, "used", user_score, user_poke, "Match Won!"
        print "current score", utal, "/", etal
        print "match", match
        return utal, match


battle()
```

this is the file import its small and isn't needed but its required for my assignment

```
# pokemon list
import random
def select_random(l):
    pokepick = random.choice(l)
    return pokepick
```

This is the Pokemon list its rather large so ill just link it 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/trlv60u48rllfc0/pokemon.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach to error-checking user input is with a while loop. For example:

```
def make_score():
    while True:
        score = raw_input('Air, Water, or Grass? ')
        if score in Attack: break
        else:
            print 'Invalid selection.'
    return score
```

This will loop to input until the user enters a string that matches one of your list items (in the Attack list).